# Table colspan and rowspan not working

Tags: html, html-table

I'm working on table for design its simple table but its not working for me, here is the design what I want:

[image]

and my code is changing after every mins for this output but didn't succeed. Code is

See the [fiddle]`(http://jsfiddle.net/su4w3ymx/1/)`

I updated my code now I'm creating it but now when I want to add notify party in third row it's messing up.

Comment: `Mr Liam` you gave me the down vote but didn't post the answer or any help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any one who could tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Refer to the answer @user3833682

Comment: Hey @user3833682 please refer my updated answer..is that what you want?

Comment: How do you know Liam downvoted your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ce5evwh7/)

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">SHIPPER/EXPORTER
            <br />W8SHIPPING
            <br />8 AVIATION CT, Savannah U.S.A.
            <br />GA 31408
            <br />TEL: +1 912 966 6820</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">BOOKING NUMBER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">EXPORTER REFERENCES</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE 1**

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ce5evwh7/1/)

**UPDATE 2**

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ce5evwh7/2/)

**UPDATE 3**

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ce5evwh7/4/) if you want to see the full structure created

Comment: I update the image can you tell me how could I do that with table only with table.

Comment: didnt get you..what do you actually want? i ve used just a table in this answer..

Comment: I update my code also but now when I want to create notify party row its messing up now.

Comment: Yes..go on @user3833682

Comment: `Mr. Lal` can you look at my new `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079673/table-in-a-table-with-rowspan-and-colspan`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">SHIPPER/EXPORTER
      <br />W8SHIPPING
      <br />8 AVIATION CT, Savannah U.S.A.
      <br />GA 31408
      <br />TEL: +1 912 966 6820</td>
    <td>BOOKING NUMBER</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      EXPORTER REFERENCES
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what about the second one?

Comment: Please check my edited one is that u were referring to?

Comment: No no there are two sections `SHIPPER/EXPORTER` and `CONSIGNEE`. What about `CONSIGNEE`.

Comment: you must post the code for that... I have edited the posted code... and more over they have the same markup as the first one you just have to paste the markup and adjust the rowspan

Comment: I update the image can you tell me that how could I do that with only table.

Comment: `Tushar Gupta` are you there?