# Table in a table with rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, html-table, pdf-generation

I'm creating table for `PDF` generating, my design is simple but when I create table in table it doesn't create that design what I want. The design is and its only crop image not complete image  [image: design]

Now after `PARTICULARS FURNISHED BY SHIPPER` the design is not working for me I only have to use `table` not `div`. How could I do that?

See the design [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su4w3ymx/1/)

`MARKS AND NUMBERS`, `#OF UNIT`, `DESCRIPTION OF PACKAGES AND GOODS`, `GROSS WEIGHT` and `MEASUREMENT` I think these are `rows` in a table or `td`, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is this your table design??

Comment: there is no need for table within table break your td and row in to smaller chunks.

Comment: this is an image I'm creating table check it at `jsfiddle` link.

Comment: after `MARKS AND NUMBERS`, `#OF UNIT`, `DESCRIPTION OF PACKAGES AND GOODS`, `GROSS WEIGHT` and `MEASUREMENT`. Is there space or these are in td?

Comment: So you want the html for this design??

Comment: Remember `Mr. Lal` only `table` not `div` or `css` simple table.

Comment: Yes...give me 5mins..

Comment: Now `Mr. Lal` see the `jsfiddle` link and I want to add value `4` below `#OF UNITS` how could I do this?

Comment: Remember one thing do this as I'm doing don't change any thing.

Comment: `Mr. Lal` I also try but didn't succeed. What to do now?

Comment: See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/mp8kj7e7/).. is this what you want???

Comment: `Mr. Lal` I think `PARTICULARS FURNISHED BY SHIPPER` could be in septate table because `MARKS AND NUMBERS`, `#OF UNITS` and others will not show the border.

Comment: This is static data I replace it to dynamic data fetching from database.

Comment: to remove the borders  you'll have to use CSS..no need of separate table..i'll show you in fiddle..

Comment: In `TCPDF` `css` doesn't work. So I'm using table.

Comment: oho..lemme just check..wait..

Comment: I updated the `jsfiddle` can you check it.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/mp8kj7e7/2/) what you want?

Comment: yes exactly thanks. Now I'll embed it to my code thanks once again.

Comment: I'll add that as my answer..Kindly mark it as accepted...

Comment: No problem I'll mark it as accepted. Can you also help me to develop next page.

Comment: Now see you reputation.

Comment: I've added that as my answer...yeah sure..please post your doubts as a new question..

Comment: ok I'll add new question if I face any problem. Thanks to you `Mr. Lal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/mp8kj7e7/2/)

Here i have used only `HTML` and no `CSS`

Some part in the HTML is as follows

```
<tr>
    <td>APHU7031756
        <br/>SEAL
        <br/>Container size
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="4">4</td>
    <td>2012 NISSAN VERSA
        <br/>2012 TOYOTA CAMRY
        <br/>2014 TOYOTA CAMRY
        <br/>2014 KIA CAMRY</td>
    <td>1237 Kg
        <br/>1295 Kg
        <br/>1295 Kg
        <br/>1295 Kg</td>
    <td>$2799
        <br/>$1114
        <br/>$1114
        <br/>$1114</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `Mr. Lal` how could I add last row `DELIVERED BY` in my table and I also update the `jsfiddle` code as my data so don't change the data as well see the link http://jsfiddle.net/mp8kj7e7/3/

Comment: And also don't change the spacing of data please. thanks

Comment: No no no I want to add `tr` and `td`. I'm adding it but top's `tr` is messing up with next one.

Comment: Right now i'm from my mobile..cant check the fiddle right now..will update you soon as possible..

Comment: ok thanks. I'll upload new image after this one completed. thanks

Comment: That is not possible using <tr> and <td> since you cannot use CSS.only way you can achieve this is using <br/>

Comment: Hi `Mr.Lal` are you there?

Comment: Can you see the `DELIVERED BY` and `RECEIVED THE ABOVE` row and its `tds`. I want to create these two sections.

Comment: yes ok..but the blank space after DELIVERED BY can only be achieved using <br/> since you cannot use CSS..

Comment: Yes I know about it I'm facing trouble creating row in centre of it.

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/mp8kj7e7/5/ I've created row I think its useless.

Comment: Can I create the line in centre just like in image.

Comment: `Mr. Lal` can I add line in centre just like in image.

Comment: which line at the center??

Comment: `DELIVERED BY` and `RECEIVED THE ABOVE` line.

Comment: now in updated code the line is not in centre see it in browser.

Comment: I'll post new question from my `PDF`.

Comment: `Mr. Lal` I'm going to post new question but this is the same `PDF` work. So need a little help

Comment: `Mr. Lal` this is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098760/table-line-in-centre-showing-data

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for table within table break your td and row in to smaller chunks. [image]

not very semantic but prob fool proof

Comment: I also post the jsfiddle link.

Comment: I'm stuck and can't add value `4` in `#OF UNITS`. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `colspan="5"` to the `td` that contains the "***PARTICULARS FURNISHED BY SHIPPER***" text

This way it will take the same space as the 5 columns below it (*since they are of the same `table`*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/su4w3ymx/2/

Comment: check my updated code... at `jsfiddle` now. Its working as per my requirement.

Comment: I'm stuck and can't add value `4` in `#OF UNITS`. Can anyone tell me?