# Table line in centre showing data

Tags: html, pdf, html-table

I'm using table for showing data and the table is working fine now but now the table looks like this.

[image]

and my code is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp8kj7e7/7/). Actually I've to show the `2.EXPORTER BALTIC AUTO SHIPPING` in one `td` and in second `td` `5.DOCUMENT NUMBER 038CHI1196412`. how could I do this.

I'm using table because in `TCPDF`css will not work so that's why I'm using table.

OR

Is there any tool which can convert `PDF` file to `html` code specially in table not in `div` or any other language like `css` just in `html table`.

Comment: Can you make it clear, now it's hard to understand

Comment: What is the question?